# Can you add bitly link in img src?

Tags: html, image, bitly

Can bitly link be added in img src? I tried it and it works on chrome but wanted to understand if it works well on all browsers and if it can work for emailers too?

**JS fiddle link:** https://jsfiddle.net/bunogL2v/

```
<img src="<bitly link>" alt="Mega Blocks">
```

Comment: In `src` you can put any valid link. For image to be shown, link must lead to valid image

Answer (score 1):

it will work as long as it is valid and not expired